# Is this RNN for text generation correctly structured ? What is to improve?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I made a **RNN** with keras for text generation. Inspired by the example given on the official [website](https://keras.io/examples/lstm_text_generation/), I decided to adapt it for french poetry and to make a *word by word* prediction instead of *character by character*.

**1) I created the training examples and the labels as following:**

From a *poetry-french.txt* file, I made up:

- a list of words contained in the text, like so:

  ```
   words = [...... '\n', '!', ',', '.', ';', ':', 'AFFECTION', 'AIMONS', 'Abandonnant', 'Abandonne' ...]
  ```
- A tokenized version of the text file named *new_text*, to make the training examples (see below), so for instance, this piece of text:

  ```
   Un poète est parti sa tombe fermée.

   Pas un chant, pas un mot dans cette langue aimée
  ```

is equivalent to this

```
['Un', 'poète', 'est', 'parti', 'sa', 'tombe', 'fermée','.', '\n', 'Pas', 'un', 'chant', ',', 'pas', 'un', 'mot', 'dans', 'cette', 'langue', 'aimée']
```

Then, I made a list of training examples, and the corresponding labels (both are matrixes of *one-shot* vectors) with this piece of code:

```
maxlen = 250 # lenght (<=> number of words) of each training example
step = 30 
X = []       # List of all training examples
Y = []       # List all corresponding labels
for i in range(0, len(new_text) - maxlen, step):
    X.append(new_text[i: i + maxlen])
    Y.append(new_text[i + maxlen])


X = 

        [ 
            [
                [0..010..0]  Un
                [0..010..0]  poète
                [0..010..0]  est
                       .....
                [0..010..0]  langue
                [0..010..0]  aimée

            ]

                .......
            [
                [0..010..0] brisant
                [0..010..0] ma
                [0..010..0] lyre
                ....
                [0..010..0] n'attendait
                [0..010..0] pas
            ]
        ]



Y = [

            [0..010..0]    '\n' THIS IS the next caracter that follows the 1st training example
                                (Un poète est blablabla langue aimée \n)

                ....

            [0..010..0]


        ]
```

Y[i] is the the word that comes after X[i] in the corpus (X[i] being a list of words, representing an extract of the text).

**2) I contructed the RNN the following way:**

```
# Parameters
params = {
          'batch_size': 12,
          'shuffle': True,
          'word_indices': word_indices,
          'indices_word': indices_word,
          'maxlen': maxlen
          }


training_generator = DataGenerator(X, Y, **params)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(words))))
model.add(Dense(len(words), activation='softmax'))

optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, steps_per_epoch = 6, epochs=22, callbacks=[print_callback])
```

When I run the training, I see two issues:

- the loss starts around 10 and I don't know if it's big or not
- sometimes the generated text after each epoch contains a lot of "\n", but in the **poetry-french.txt** there are never more than 3 "\n" in a row.

So comes two questions:

1) Do you think the overall structure of my RNN is correct ?

2) How can I "tell" the network that it is doing wrong when generating more than 3 "\n" in a row ?

I hope I was clear in my explanation, I will edit the post if necessary.

[Here](https://github.com/aymeric75/IA/) is the GitHub link of my code

Thanks a lot !

Aymeric